# Removing multiple git commits from history

Tags: git, git-commit, git-rewrite-history

I am working on a project with some classmates and we are using git for version control. One of the group members had is username set to something other than the user name for the git account he was using, so after making several commits, he did not show up as a contributor. In trying to fix this, he accidentally made a copy of every commit that was made, with his own user name has the author.

Is there any way to go through and delete these duplicates from the history without actually changing the state of the repo?

**Edit:**
For example, suppose the repo's commit history is this:

```
"Updated readme" - joesmith0x539 

"Added UI framework" - johnnybravo22
```

After the other contributor tried changing his user name from johnnybravo22 to let's say johnnyb32, the history became:

```
"Updated readme" - joesmith0x539 

"Updated readme" - johnnyb32 

"Added UI framework" - johnnybravo22 

"Added UI framework" - johnnyb32
```

I now want to delete all of the unnecessary duplicates he made.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use [SQUASH COMMITS](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History). But
[Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages) let other developers by providing an alternate version of the same change.

> Don’t include any commit you’ve already pushed to a central server –
> doing so will confuse other developers by providing an alternate
> version of the same change.

Let me take an example

**1:**    `git rebase -i HEAD~4` # you would see last four commits

**2:** This command pop-up en editor with few commands

```
pick 44d59fa Add capybaras page.
pick 7d2edea Add capybaras to index.
pick 6e8e5d6 Change plural on detail page to 'capybara'.
pick e8005f4 Change plural on index page to 'capybara'.
```

**3:** They 2 were better off as one commit.

```
pick 44d59fa Add capybaras page.
pick 7d2edea Add capybaras to index.
pick 6e8e5d6 Change plural on detail page to 'capybara'.
squash e8005f4 Change plural on index page to 'capybara'.
```

**Note:** `squash` merges a commit with the previous commit

**4:** Another editor pops up, with the commits being squashed

```
# This is a combination of 2 commits.
# The first commit's message is:

Change plural on detail page to 'capybara'.

# This is the 2nd commit message:

Change plural on index page to 'capybara'.

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit
```

**5:** Enter the message for the new commit, save, and exit

**6:** `git log --oneline`

World would be happy again!!! and Hope this help you!

**Note:** This will "change the state of the repo" in the sense that anything following the deleted commits will have a new commit ID.

Comment: @jwbcse - Accept the answer if given an answer worked for you.